# Crash when trying to use Active Label for a caption

Tags: swift, crash, label, hashtag

I am getting a crash when trying to use Active Label for the users captions. I thought it was because some of the captions I added previously did not contain any of the enabled types. So I made a post stating "This is a post with #hashtags and a @userhandle." The app still crashes, did I miss a step or is something wrong?

```
        captionLabel.text = posts?.caption

        let customType = ActiveType.custom(pattern: "\(captionLabel)\\b")

        captionLabel.enabledTypes = [.mention, .hashtag, .url, customType]


        captionLabel.customize { (label) in
            label.text = "\(captionLabel)"
            label.textColor = .black
            label.numberOfLines = 0

        }`
```

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x600003a7c100)

Comment: Pattern is a String? 
If the answer is yes, try `(pattern: "\(captionLabel.text)\\b")`  instead of `(pattern: "\(captionLabel)\\b")`

Comment: Can you make this an answer so I can accept it for you mate? I dont know why some one disliked the question but whatever

Comment: Sure, answer made!

Comment: @Clint I had this same problem, I upvoted you to neutralise the downvote.

Comment: @captain_haddock. Thanks! I hope the answer helped as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pattern is a String, so, try `(pattern: "\(captionLabel.text)\\b")` instead of `(pattern: "\(captionLabel)\\b")`

If you try init pattern with `\(captionLabel)`, you will be using the label.
You need to use the text of that label.